# Kernel on two functions?

Tags: kernel-trick, functional-data-analysis

I am curious whether there are any literatures considering kernel functions whose inputs are two functions. For example I would like consider two 1-Liptchiz mappings $\pi, \sigma:\mathbb{R}^M\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, and maybe on possible kernel function on this space is $k(\pi, \sigma)=\int\pi(\bf{x})\sigma(x)dx$?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at [separable convolutions](https://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2006/10/04/separable-convolution/#1), or separable filters which are used in image processing.